# Java Swing Drawing A Rectangle

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a simple app that visualised sorting algorithms, but have gotten stuck trying to draw a rectangle (these will later represent each number in the array). I have tried alot of tutorials, and my code compiles, but it just makes an empty screen when ran. Have I missed something obvious?

```java
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

class DrawRectangle extends JComponent{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.PINK);
        Rectangle2D rect=new Rectangle2D.Double(50,50,200,200);
        g2.draw(rect);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }
}

public class Sorter {  
    static int numElements = 20; 
    static int width = 800;
    static int height = 500;

    public void newList(){

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        
        for(int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++){
            int randomNum = rand.nextInt(100);
            nums.add(randomNum);
        }

        // Create J Frame
        JFrame f=new JFrame(); 
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
        int arrWidth = width - 200;
        int eachCol = arrWidth / nums.size();
        for(int i = 0; i <= numElements; i++){

        }
        
        f.setSize(width,height);
        f.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers  
        f.setVisible(true);//making the frame visible  
        
        DrawRectangle rec= new DrawRectangle();
        f.add(rec);
        
        f.add(new DrawRectangle());
        f.repaint();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the README for this [Bubble Sort Animation](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/bubble-sort-animation).  A Swing application that animates sorting algorithms is definitely not simple.

Comment: 1) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers 2) *i''m trying to make a simple app that visualised sorting algorithms,* - check out [Bubble Sort Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196198/bubble-sort-animation) for a different approach to animation for the next step of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your DrawRectangle is never given any size (height & width). You could add

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
  return new Dimension(200,200);
}
```

to DrawRectangle and turn the layoutmanger back on (preferred solution). Or you could manually setSize/setBounds of both the DrawRectangle and the Frame.

Comment: You can look at https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/ for a complete MVC solution for drawing and managing shapes in swing. Start by looking at AreaManager

Answer (score 3):

Usually, when you want to draw shapes, you define a class that extends `javax.swing.JPanel` (and not `JComponent`) and you override method `paintComponent` (as you have done).

The first line in the overridden `paintComponent` method should almost always be a call to the superclass method, i.e.

```java
super.paintComponent(g);
```

As stated in [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

> in Swing, your GUI creation code should be placed on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)

There is no need to set the layout to null in your `JFrame`. There is also no need to explicitly call method `repaint`.

You should add all the components to the `JFrame` before calling method `setVisible`.

The following code displays a pink rectangle in a `JFrame`. Note that I removed the irrelevant code concerning generating random numbers since that does not affect your desired result of displaying a rectangle.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class DrawRectangle extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(Color.PINK);
        Rectangle2D rect=new Rectangle2D.Double(50,50,200,200);
        g2.draw(rect);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }
}

public class Sorter {
    static int width = 800;
    static int height = 500;

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new DrawRectangle());
        f.setSize(width,height);
        f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Sorter sorter = new Sorter();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> sorter.createAndDisplayGui());
    }  
}
```

Note that in the tutorial, *Performing Custom Painting*, they call method `invokeLater` of class `SwingUtilities`. That method merely invokes the method in class `EventQueue` so I just call the `EventQueue` method directly.

Here is a screen capture.

[image: screen capture]