# java JFrame update on resizing the window, but not on its own

Tags: java, swing

I am making a program that inputs 5 integers and sort them visually by displaying the lines representing the number, but when I run the program, the logic works fine but line's position changes when I resize the window of the jframe, instead of automatically changing the position, here is my code

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class visualSorter extends Canvas
{
    static int n = 5, ar[] = new int[n],height;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
    public static void main(String args[])
    {    
        try
        {
            Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(int i = 0; i < 5;i++)
            {
                ar[i] = ob.nextInt();
            }
            ob.close();
            visualSorter vs = new visualSorter();
            vs.frame();

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            vs.sort();
            
        }

        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }


    void frame()
    {
        
        Canvas cn = new visualSorter();
        cn.setSize(1920,1080);
        frame.add(cn);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    

    void sort()
    {
        try
        {
            int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)    
        {    
          for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)    
            {    
                if(ar[j] < ar[i])    
                {    
                    temp = ar[i];    
                    ar[i] = ar[j];    
                    ar[j] = temp;     
                }     
            }     
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            revalidate();
        } 
        repaint();
        
        }

        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

        int xDistance = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            xDistance+=200;
            height = ar[j]*100;
            g2d.setColor(Color.green);
            g2d.fillRect(0+xDistance,0,10,height);
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate any help, my code might be quite bad so please give me some suggestions to improve and also some tips.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: An animation GUI is way more complicated than you think.  First, don't mix Scanner and a GUI.  A Scanner is process-driven, while a GUI is event-driven.  A Scanner and a GUI don't play well together.  Take a look at my [bubble sort animation](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/bubble-sort-animation) readme to see what I mean.

Comment: 1) Don't use a Canvas, that is an AWT component. For Swing you should use a `JPanel` or `JComponent`. Then you override `paintComponent(...)` instead of paint(). You need to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`. 2) Don't use a "sleep" method for animation. Instead you should use a `Swing Timer` for animation. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196198/bubble-sort-animation for a working example using the above concepts.