# How can I get the closest to a "pause" effect in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have to program a small game in Java using Swing and I need to do a very specific thing which I can't figure out for the life of me.

Here's the problem-method:

```
static void aiTurn() {

        boolean attackableNeighbour = true;

        while (attackableNeighbour) {
            attackableNeighbour = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < DicePanel.ROWS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < DicePanel.COLUMNS; j++) {
                    if (!cells[i][j].getIsPlayer()) {
                        int min = 9;
                        int minI = 0;
                        int minJ = 0;

                        for (int neighbourI = Math.max(0, i - 1); 
                            neighbourI <= Math.min(i + 1, cells.length - 1); neighbourI++) {
                            for (int neighbourJ = Math.max(0, j - 1); 
                                neighbourJ <= Math.min(j + 1, cells[0].length - 1); neighbourJ++) {
                                if (neighbourI != i && neighbourJ != j
                                    && cells[neighbourI][neighbourJ].getIsPlayer() 
                                    && cells[neighbourI][neighbourJ].getDiceNumber() < min) {
                                    min = cells[neighbourI][neighbourJ].getDiceNumber();
                                    minI = neighbourI;
                                    minJ = neighbourJ;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (cells[i][j].getDiceNumber() >= min) {
                            attackableNeighbour = true;

                            cells[minI][minJ].setBackground(new Color(119, 82, 168));
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(new Color(121, 204, 88));

                            //pause here for a second (background needs to change)

                            attackAI(i, j, minI, minJ);

                            cells[i][j].setBackground(new Color(61, 153, 49));
                            if (cells[minI][minJ].getIsPlayer()) {
                                cells[minI][minJ].setBackground(new Color(100, 50, 168));
                            }

                            //pause here as well
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

What I need to do is to be able to pause there. The problem is, since all of this is in the EDT, I can't just use a timer or use `Thread.sleep()` - the GUI won't update. The effect I want to have is for the GUI to update according to my code, without it progressing to the next change.

I've tried using a different thread for the logic, but no matter what I tried, it's either not working or the code on the EDT (the for loop) keeps on going and the new thread is delayed so badly that it breaks the whole system.

Here's something that I tried:

```
 if (cells[i][j].getDiceNumber() >= min) {
     attackableNeighbour = true;

     final int altMinI = minI;
     final int altMinJ = minJ;
     final int altI = i;
     final int altJ = j;

     cells[minI][minJ].setBackground(new Color(119, 82, 168));
     cells[i][j].setBackground(new Color(121, 204, 88));

     SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<Object, String>() {
         @Override
         protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
             attackAI(altI, altJ, altMinI, altMinJ);
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             cells[i][j].setBackground(new Color(61, 153, 49));
             if (cells[minI][minJ].getIsPlayer()) {
                 cells[minI][minJ].setBackground(new Color(100, 50, 168));
             }
             return null;
         }
     };
     worker.execute();
}
```

This breaks the game because the method `attackAI()` gets called long after the initial for loop is over. I've tried reading so many posts regarding multithreading and I'm at a loss. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't use for loops for animation. Instead use a Swing Timer to schedule the animation. Then you can stop/pause the animation as required. Based on your simple code your Timer would stop when "attackableNeighbour" is false. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028681/131872 for an example. Or maybe you could use a SwingWorker with your for loops. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196256/131872 for an example of this approach.

Comment: I think what you need to do is to separate the game state and the rendering. Maybe read up on game states and game loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post an answer to my own question for anyone who was as stuck as I was. Thank you to camickr; his comment helped me achieve what I wanted to do.

Here's the updated code that works as I wanted it to:

```
static void aiTurn() {

SwingWorker<Object, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Object, String>() {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        boolean attackableNeighbour = true;

        while (attackableNeighbour) {
            attackableNeighbour = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < DicePanel.ROWS; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < DicePanel.COLUMNS; j++) {
                    if (!cells[i][j].getIsPlayer() && cells[i][j].getDiceNumber() > 1) {
                        int min = 9;
                        int minI = 0;
                        int minJ = 0;

                        for (int neighbourI = Math.max(0, i - 1); 
                            neighbourI <= Math.min(i + 1, cells.length - 1); neighbourI++) {
                            for (int neighbourJ = Math.max(0, j - 1); 
                                neighbourJ <= Math.min(j + 1, cells[0].length - 1); neighbourJ++) {
                                if (neighbourI != i && neighbourJ != j
                                    && cells[neighbourI][neighbourJ].getIsPlayer() 
                                    && cells[neighbourI][neighbourJ].getDiceNumber() < min) {
                                    min = cells[neighbourI][neighbourJ].getDiceNumber();
                                    minI = neighbourI;
                                    minJ = neighbourJ;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (cells[i][j].getDiceNumber() >= min) {
                            attackableNeighbour = true;

                            Thread.sleep(700);

                            cells[minI][minJ].setBackground(new Color(119, 82, 168));
                            cells[i][j].setBackground(new Color(121, 204, 88));

                            Thread.sleep(1000);

                            attackAI(i, j, minI, minJ);

                            cells[i][j].setBackground(new Color(61, 153, 49));
                            if (cells[minI][minJ].getIsPlayer()) {
                                cells[minI][minJ].setBackground(new Color(100, 50, 168));
                            }

                            Thread.sleep(300);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        endTurnAI();
        return null;
    }
};

worker.execute(); }
```

My oversight was that, when I'd put only what's inside the for-loops in a different thread, the loops would continue while the thread was sleeping, so it would get completely delayed.

But since every GUI change happens in the event thread, I can just put the whole for-loops in a different thread, then sleep it when I wanted it to pause - the GUI would still change (since the EDT is empty at the time) and nothing would be delayed because everything still essentially works in a single thread.