Starting X and sometimes Y coordinate of JFrame is displaced
Just recently started playing around more with Swing and right now I am trying to build an Algorythm Visualiser. The array being displayed is displaced. The starting X coordinate is shifted to the right. After playing around it seems that the Dimensions of the array somehow do not match the size of window.
I tried shifting around the array to both sides, played around with the size of bars and dimensions of the array, but it still does not match. I was hoping to find probably some mathematical mistake I made when trying to calculate the dimensions of the individual bars and the array.
public class SortArray extends JPanel {

    public static final int WIN_WIDTH = 1000;
    public static final int WIN_HEIGHT = WIN_WIDTH * 9 / 16 ; // 562

    private static final int SIZE = 500;
    private static final float INCREMENT = (float) WIN_HEIGHT / SIZE;

    private static final float BAR_WIDTH = (float) WIN_WIDTH / SIZE;

    private float[] array = new float[SIZE];

    private SwingWorker<Void,Void> sorter;
    
    public SortArray() {

        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        // setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));  
        
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        fillArray(array);

        // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
        // System.out.println(BAR_WIDTH);
        // shuffleArray(array);
        // sorter(array);

        repaint();
    }

    public void sorter(float[] array){
        
        sorter = new SwingWorker<>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException {

            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE - i - 1; j++) {

                    if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
                        swap(j, j + 1);

                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
                return null;
            }
            
        };

        sorter.execute();

    }

    public void fillArray(float[] array){

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            
            array[i] = i * INCREMENT;
        }
    }

    public void shuffleArray(float[] array){
        
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            int randomIndexToSwap = rand.nextInt(SIZE);
            swap(i,randomIndexToSwap);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    }



    public void swap(int indexA, int indexB){
        float temp = array[indexA];

        array[indexA] = array[indexB];
        array[indexB] = temp;

    }


    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Rectangle2D.Float rect;
        

            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

                g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);


                
                float height = array[i];
                float beginX = i * BAR_WIDTH;
                float beginY = WIN_HEIGHT - height;

                if(i==1){
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    System.out.println("First(1) position: " + "["+beginX + ", " + beginY + "]" + " height: " + height);
                    System.out.println(WIN_HEIGHT);
                }
                if(i==SIZE-1){
                    g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                    System.out.println("Last(999) position: " + "["+beginX + ", " + beginY + "]" + " height: " + height);
                    System.out.println(WIN_HEIGHT);
                }

                System.out.println(i);

                rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(beginX, beginY, BAR_WIDTH, height);
                
                // rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(i * BAR_WIDTH, 0, BAR_WIDTH, array[i]);

                
                g2d.fill(rect);

        }    

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WIN_HEIGHT, WIN_WIDTH);
    }


    public int arraySize() {
        return array.length;
    }


}

    public Display(){

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            frame = new JFrame("Algorythm Visualiser");
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.validate();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        

            sortArray = new SortArray();
            sortArray.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
            frame.add(sortArray);

    
            frame.setSize(SortArray.WIN_WIDTH, SortArray.WIN_HEIGHT);


        });
        
    }


Check out getInsets()

You also need to study the (excellent) API documentation of SwingWorker. You're not using it correctly

You should not be setting the size of the SortArray panel. Instead you override the getPreferredSize() method to return the appropriate dimension. Then after adding the panel to the frame you pack() the frame. Now the frame size will include the decorations of the frame. Check out this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64196256/131872 of a Bubble Sort animation.

camickr is of course right but the point is you have two choices: A. fix the size of the window or B. do appropriate scaling calculations for your custom painting - what do you do when the user makes the window 50px square?

Thank you guys, managed to make it work:)

@domk please post your solution as an answer for future references, thank you.
